# High charts Average time circle plot position changes

Tags: highcharts

Am using high charts, when am calculating the average time and plotting the pin position slightly changed. Here am attaching the screen shot, please have a look on it and help me out from this. Thank you.

Here is my series,

```
 var data = [
            {
                name: 'No. of potholes',
                data: seriesArray,
                stack: 'North',
                color: 'lightblue'
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Average',
                data: seriesAvg,
                color: 'orange',
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: 'orange',
                    fillColor: 'white'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'KPI',
                color: 'grey'
            },
        ]
```

The plotting circle position has been changed:
[image]

Comment: Can you post your whole chart code?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the **`grouping`** functionality (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.grouping):

When it is enabled each column series has a reserved space in every group. There're two column series in your chart. The second column series occupies half of the space in each group even though it has no data.

Set `grouping` to `false` to prevent this unwanted behavior.

Comment: Hello Kamil., thanks for your update let me check it out.